# UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite – GridSearchCV for MultiOutputClassifier(MLPClassifier)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, multiclass-classification

I am trying out scikit-learn for the first time, for a **Multi-Output Multi-Class text classification** problem. I am attempting to use `GridSearchCV` to optimize the parameters of `MLPClassifier` for this purpose.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df.fillna('', inplace=True) #Replaces NaNs with "" in the DataFrame (which would be considered a viable choice in this multi-classification model)

x_features = df['input_text']
y_labels = df[['output_text_label_1', 'output_text_label_2']]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_features, y_labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=7)
```

When I attempt to set up a `Pipeline` for `MultiOutputClassifier(MLPClassifier())` without any parameter optimization, `pipe.score` gives a score of ~0.837, which seems to suggest that the above code is doing something. Running `pipe.predict()` on some test strings seems to yield relatively adequate output results.

```
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('cv', CountVectorizer()),
                       ('mlpc', MultiOutputClassifier(MLPClassifier()))])

pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)

pipe.score(x_test, y_test)
```

However, when attempting to separately use `GridSearchCV` using the below starting code from another [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71906021/4909923), I run into a problem:

```
mlpc = MLPClassifier(solver='adam',
                     learning_rate_init=0.01,
                     max_iter=300,
                     activation='relu',
                     early_stopping=True)
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('cv', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1))),
                       ('scale', StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),
                       ('mlpc', MultiOutputClassifier(mlpc))])
search_space = {
    'cv__max_df': (0.9, 0.95, 0.99),
    'cv__min_df': (0.01, 0.05, 0.1),
    'mlpc__estimator__alpha': 10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 5),
    'mlpc__estimator__hidden_layer_sizes': ((64, 32), (128, 64),
                                            (64, 32, 16), (128, 64, 32)),
    'mlpc__estimator__tol': (1e-3, 5e-3, 1e-4),
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, search_space, scoring='accuracy', error_score='raise', n_jobs=-1)

grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

This warning seems to be related to a scoring problem, `UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite`:

```
UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
  warnings.warn(
```

The `.shape` of `x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train`, `y_test` are `(3036,)` `(1302,)` `(3036, 2)` `(1302, 2)` respectively. The contents are all strings, and as you can see in the code above, I have replaced many occurrences of NaN into empty strings `""`, which should be a viable option for the model (basically having it select None as a class):

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True) #Replaces NaNs with "" in the DataFrame (which would be considered a viable choice in this multi-classification model)
```

I have tried other `scoring=` methods in `GridSearchCV`: `roc_auc_ovr` and `f1_macro`, with essentially the same problem.

If I include in `GridSearchCV` the following option: `error_score='raise'`, I get the error: `ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported`.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-14bccd802d09> in <module>
     21 #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265110/does-gridsearchcv-not-support-multi-class
     22 
---> 23 grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)

~/condaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    889                 return results
    890 
--> 891             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    892 
    893             # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable

~/condaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1390     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1391         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1392         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1393 
   1394 

~/condaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    836                     )
    837 
--> 838                 out = parallel(
    839                     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    840                         clone(base_estimator),

~/condaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1059 
   1060             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1061                 self.retrieve()
   1062             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1063             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

~/condaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    938             try:
    939                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 940                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    941                 else:
    942                     self._output.extend(job.get())

~/condaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    540         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    541         try:
--> 542             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    543         except CfTimeoutError as e:
    544             raise TimeoutError from e

~/condaenv/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    444                     raise CancelledError()
    445                 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 446                     return self.__get_result()
    447                 else:
    448                     raise TimeoutError()

~/condaenv/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    389         if self._exception:
    390             try:
--> 391                 raise self._exception
    392             finally:
    393                 # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception

ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported
```

When looking around for solutions, I spotted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653301/4909923) which suggests that `CountVectorizer` expects 1D inputs. I have two features in my `.shape` for Multi-Output. I have no idea if this answer is correct, since I am evaluating scikit-learn for the first time. The answer proposes to use `ColumnTransformer` to solve this, but I need a code example to understand how if this is indeed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `y` has multiple columns, not your `X`, so the `CountVectorizer` isn't the issue.  Rather, the problem is that you have two targets each with more than two possible outcomes.  From [the User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html), `MLPClassifier` supports multilabel, but not multi-output multiclass.  [Later](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multiclass-multioutput-classification) in the same page, there is an additional warning about scoring:

> **Warning:** At present, no metric in `sklearn.metrics` supports the multiclass-multioutput classification task.

so even if you wrapped your classifier in e.g. `MultiOutputClassifier` the scoring for the grid search would fail.  I think you should be able to define a custom scorer to make this work?  You might also consider whether your labels are really properly ordered as label_1 and label_2, or whether this can be cast as a multilabel problem, binarizing the targets?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might have been confused about the scope of what wrapping `MLPClassifier` within `MultiOutputClassifier` could achieve. Are you implying that this wrapping will not work, or do you believe that it can work but that it needs a custom scorer? And would you rather propose that I try to use one of the `multiclass-multioutput` estimators (from the User Guide page)? I think `ensemble.RandomForestClassifier` was the only one I could run out-of-the box with the above code, but `MultiOutputClassifier(MLPClassifier)` gave a higher `Pipeline.score` which is why I focused on it.

Comment: The wrapping should work with a custom scorer; but I'm surprised the random forest didn't also have an issue with scoring in the search, maybe the warning in the documentation is now incorrect? I would suggest first verifying that multioutput is the right structure for your problem, and then building a custom metric (or maybe just making a separate model for each output).